# Magento 2: Is it no longer possible to load Quotes by ID?

Tags: magento2, cart, quote

In the past, to load a quote by id, i used to use the factory:

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ....
}
```

But since moving on, it is more recommended to use the service contract:

```
protected $cartRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteRepository = $cartRepository;
    ....
}
```

However this will give me a Cart API, and some of the functions available in Quote like `getAllItems` i cannot use via the Cart service, the function `getItems` only lists visible ones (meaning it will exclude children items of a configurable item). Is this designed to be this way in order to restrict bad practices or how can i retrieve a quote using the quote_id or the Cart service?

Comment: Generally speaking I only ever fetch visible items from cart. Can you provide more information on why this is a problem for you?

Comment: @DominicXigen Working with Magento 1, sometimes there are values only saved in simples not configurables (probably because of bad codes from bad 3rd party modules). I haven't run into that issue in M2 yet, but because i was used to getAllItems, so just wondering.